# Continuous maps $f,g$ such that $\left.f\right|A = \left.g\right|A$. Show that $\left.f\right|\overline{A} = \left.g\right|\overline{A}$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

> Let $f,g : X \to Y$ be continous maps and $A \subset X$ such that $\left.f\right|A = \left.g\right|A$. Show that $\left.f\right|\overline{A} = \left.g\right|\overline{A}$

According to Wikipedia the restrictions can be represented as graphs the following way $G(\left.f\right|A)= \{(x,f(x)) \in G(f) \mid x \in A\}$ so I'm wondering if this should be proven by showing that $G(\left.f\right|\overline{A})=G(\left.g\right|\overline{A})$ e.g showing that two sets are equal or am I completely wrong here?

Comment: What are $X$ and $Y$?

Comment: $X$ and $Y$ seems to be just a arbitary sets?

Comment: That's one way. Or show that $f(x)=g(x)$ for all $«\in \overline A$ if $f(x)=g(x)$ for all $«\in A$

Comment: Then what does it mean to say that a function from an arbitrary set to another arbitrary set is continuous?

Comment: I see. $X$ and $Y$ are probably then metric spaces instead of arbitary sets.

Comment: $X, Y$ are topological spaces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is trivial if we argue using ``net''. We need the assumption
that $Y$ is Hausdorff.

Let $x\in\bar{A}$. Choose a net $(x_{\alpha})$ in $A$ such that
$x_{\alpha}\rightarrow x$. Define $y_{\alpha}=f(x_{\alpha})=g(x_{\alpha})$.
Since $f$ is continuous at $x$, we have that $y_{\alpha}\rightarrow f(x)$.
Since $g$ is also continuous at $x$, we have that $y_{\alpha}\rightarrow g(x)$.
Finally, that $Y$ is Hausdorff implies that the limit of the net
$(y_{\alpha})$ is unique. Hence, $f(x)=g(x)$.

If $Y$ is not Hausdorff, in general, we cannot conclude that $f\mid_{\bar{A}}=g\mid_{\bar{A}}$.
Counter-example: Let $X=\mathbb{R}$, equipped with the usual topology.
Let $Y=\mathbb{R}$, equipped with the trivial topology $\{\emptyset,\mathbb{R}\}$.
Define $f(x)=x$ and $g(x)=\begin{cases}
x, & \mbox{if }x<1\\
0, & \mbox{if }x\geq1
\end{cases}.$ Let $A=[0,1)$, then $\bar{A}=[0,1]$. Clearly, $f$ and $g$ are
continuous because the topology of $Y$ is the trivial topology. Moreover,
$f\mid_{A}=g\mid_{A}$. However, $f\mid_{\bar{A}}\neq g\mid_{\bar{A}}$
because $f(1)\neq g(1)$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $X=\Bbb R$ with standard topology and $Y=\Bbb R\cup \{*\}$. Let $\pi\colon Y\to X$, $y\mapsto \begin{cases}0&y=*\\y&y\ne *\end{cases}$. To turn $Y$ into a topological space, declare a set $U\subseteq Y$ open iff $\pi(U)$ is open in $\Bbb R$.
Define $f\colon X\to Y$, $x\mapsto \begin{cases}*&x=0\\x&x\ne 0\end{cases}$ and let $g$ be the inclusion map. For open $U\subseteq Y$, we have that $f^{-1}(U), g^{-1}(U)$ are $\pi (U)$ or $\pi(U)\setminus \{0\}$, so certainly open. Thus $f,g$ are continuous. With $A=\Bbb R\setminus\{0\}$, we have $f|_A=g|_A$, but as $\overline A=X$, we do not have $f|_{\overline A}=g|_{\overline A}$.